# Find the shortest path in an graph containing at least one green edge

Tags: algorithm, graph

I need to find an algorithm to find the shortest path from v_s to v_t in an undirected graph G1 colored green and black in a random way and I have to pass on at least one green edge.

My solution (not sure about the best one):

1. To duplicate the graph G1 to G2
2. In G1 to disconnect all edges to v_t
3. Add edges from all nodes connected to green edges in G1 to G2 for the same node.
   For example if we have a green edge with nodes (v1,u1) in G1
   we add a node from v1 to u2
4. I run BFS to find shortest path from v_s to v_t (which will be in G2).
   By doing this I force the BFS to pass on a green edge to reach v_t

Comment: That sounds like a great solution. What specifically is your question?

Comment: An A* search devolves into BFS in the worst case, but also has the advantage that you can include a heuristic to incorporate the constraint that the solution needs a green edge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution is great, But I'd use Dijstra's algorithm instead of BFS. It is usually much more efficient, But this depends on the data as in the worst case it can search as much as BFS but pay the extra overhead of the priority-queue.

Another nice solution, which is a correction of Benjamin's solution

1. Run Dijstras' single-source-shortest-path twice, once from the source, once from the target
2. Pass through all green edges. For each, sum the path coming from source and the path coming from target. 
   Chose the shortest of those.

This solution is more intuitive to me then yours, but I don't see a real advantage of one over the other.

Answer (score 0):

My approach would be to run a bi-directional Dijkstra search, and then only allow one branch of each search to meet when at least one of the branches contains a green edge.

This is in similar to your own approach, but does not require copying the graph into G2.